# zsh can not find python path

Tags: python, zsh

I'm trying to add the python path to my .zshrc, but unfortunately I couldn't.
I wrote it like this in my .zshrc file:

```
alias python="'C:\\Users\\BA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.10\\Python 3.10 (64-bit)'"
```

So after executing `python` in the terminal, you are going to get the following error:

`zsh: command not found: C:\Users\BA\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu \Programs\Python 3.10\Python 3.10 (64-bit)`

Could some one help me! I think this error is happening because of the syntax of the path, maybe I didn't write it right.

Best regards

Comment: That file isn't an executable, it's a menu entry. You need to invoke the _actual executable_. That's not in the `Start Menu` directory, but rather is somewhere else; exactly where depends on how you installed Python.

Comment: Don't define this alias in the first place. Make sure the correct directory is in your `PATH` variable instead.

Comment: You don't to call Python from its shortcut in your Start Menu, but from its real path.

Comment: I printed the $PATH & I became the following result: from where to where should I copy the python path?! As I see there is a Python in the $PATH:
`/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/
mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/BA/AppData
/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/BA/AppData/Local/Programs
/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/BA/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/ `

I wrote here in the comment just a part of the $PATH where there a Python word

Comment: `/mnt/c/Users/BA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts` is typically where a Python package you install with `pip` (for use by Python 3.10) will have its executables created, not where the Python interpreter itself goes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, ...well, there _is_ a reason to double up the quotes here: the outer quotes hold the alias together into a single argument, the inner quotes make that argument, when substituted at the beginning of a command line, expand to exactly one word.

Comment: @Dr.IT79, right-click on the start menu entry for Python, go to "properties"; nose around there and you should be able to find the location that the `.lnk` file points to.

Comment: @Dr.IT79, btw, there are some extra spaces in the PATH you showed us that don't make much sense. I hope they're just an artifact of how it was copied-and-pasted and not really part of the value.

Comment: ...if you installed Python 3.10 for just one user, instead of globally, it's _possible_ that `/mnt/c/Users/BA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/` might be where `python.exe` is, but you're better equipped to test that than anyone else here. And if that _is_ where the executable is, you should be able to just delete the alias and start python without it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I found the main path as ou told me, and now waht should I do?

`C:\Users\BA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe`

Comment: If `C:\Users\BA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` is in your PATH, you should be able to just run `python` with no alias at all. (Whether `/mnt/c` should be there or not, and whether to use backslashes or forward slashes depends on exactly which context you're checking PATH in -- the prefix shouldn't be there, and the slashes need to be backslashes, for native Windows executables).

Comment: when I'm using .zsh it will cause an error, that python not found. On the other hand, when I use another terminal like git bash then it can find it.
I would to add python to .zsh

Comment: You have backslashes (`\ `) in your path. This does not look right. A backslash is a special escape character for zsh. The path separation character is a forward slash (`/`). Do a `pwd` on your command line, to get an idea of how a correct path should look like on your system.